# MySQL Triggers (Before Insert)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables `inspect`, with columns `inspect_id (pk), inspect_loc`  and `duplicate_inspect` with columns `inspect_id, inspect_loc`. I need a MySQL trigger that inserts Data into `duplicate_inspect` only if the data being inserted into `inspect` is already available.

Answer (score 0):

For example ..

```
CREATE TRIGGER duplicate 
BEFORE INSERT ON duplicate_inspect
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.inspect_id = inspect_id THEN
    INSERT INTO duplicate_inspect (inspect_id,inspect_loc) values('','');
  END IF;
END
```

I can't test now, but you need the values. (i think all code it's ok).

Comment: I get error 1062: duplicate entry for primary key whenever I try insert data

Comment: I test it when i get home. (tonight) You have set any index? or you forget to set AI ?